# Show that the probability of the sample $S$ is the probability of $S_1 S_2$.

Tags: statistics, sampling, sampling-theory

> Let $U$ be the population with a size of $N$, and let $n_1$ and $n_2$ be
> the sizes of two samples $S_1$ and $S_2$, respectively. Let the sample
> $S = S_1 U S_2$ with size $n = n_1 + n_2$. Show that the probability
> of selecting this sample is
>
> $\frac{1}{N \choose n_1} \cdot \frac{1}{N-n_1 \choose n_2}= 
>  \frac{1}{N\choose n}$.

I've gotten this formula reduced down to
$\frac{n_1! n_2! (N-n)!}{N!} = \frac{(n-n_2)!n_2!(N-n)!}{N!}$ but I can't figure out how to get rid of the $n_1!n_2!$ values. I know the final answer needs to be

$\frac{n!(N-n)!}{N!} = \frac{1}{N \choose n}$.

Any tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I get this.

$\frac{1}{N \choose n_1} \cdot \frac{1}{N-n_1 \choose n_2}= 
\frac{1}{N\choose n}
$

is the same as

${N \choose n_1}{N-n_1 \choose n_2}= 
{N\choose n}
$

$\begin{array}\\
{N \choose n_1} {N-n_1 \choose n_2}
&=\frac{N!(N-n_1)!}{(N-n_1)!n_1!n_2!(N-n_1-n_2)!}\\
&=\frac{N!}{n_1!n_2!(N-n_1-n_2)!}\\
&=\frac{N!}{n_1!n_2!(N-n)!}\qquad n=n_1+n_2\\
&=\frac{n!N!}{n_1!n_2!n!(N-n)!}\\
&={n \choose n_1}{N \choose n}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Shouldn't the final answer just be $N\choose n$, though? I think that's what the question was asking for.

Comment: is there a way to get rid of the $n \choose n_1$ in your final answer?

Comment: Not that I can see.